# Question about blending 2 images together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at the sample code from the link below (Example 2: Italy Street Image with Wave Style).

https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/blob/master/notebooks/Ch12_Deep_Learning_for_Computer_Vision/Neural%20Style%20Transfer%20Results%20-%20High%20Resolution.ipynb

Also, looking at input images from the link below.

https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/tree/master/notebooks/Ch12_Deep_Learning_for_Computer_Vision/results/italy%20street

My question is this.  Why is iteration_1.png to iteration_20.png being read into the code?

```
is_content_image = io.imread('results/italy street/italy_street.jpg')
is_style_image = io.imread('results/italy street/style1.png')
is_iter1 = io.imread('results/italy street/style_transfer_result_italy_street_gatys_at_iteration_1.png')
is_iter5 = io.imread('results/italy street/style_transfer_result_italy_street_gatys_at_iteration_5.png')
is_iter10 = io.imread('results/italy street/style_transfer_result_italy_street_gatys_at_iteration_10.png')
is_iter15 = io.imread('results/italy street/style_transfer_result_italy_street_gatys_at_iteration_15.png')
is_iter20 = io.imread('results/italy street/style_transfer_result_italy_street_gatys_at_iteration_20.png')
```

It seems like you would read in italy_street.jpg and style1.png, and the code should do the work of blending the images together, so after several iterations they are merged into a contamination of the two images.  This seems intuitive, rather than doing 'io.imread' for several images, and then saving each image after each iteration.  Am I missing something basic here?  Or, is there a better demo other there, which shows how to blend two images together?  Thanks for the look.